# ping: show only results

Tags: shell, ping

Is it possible to only show the amount of milliseconds when pinging instead of the whole result page?

I want to check if my servers are online, so I want to return "OK xyz ms" or "FAIL". I am currently doing this like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
ergebnis=$(ping -qc1 google.com) 
ok=$?
avg=$(echo -e "$ergebnis"  | tail -n1 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -f 2 -d "/")

if [ $ok -eq 0 ]
then
        echo "OK $avg ms"
else
        echo "FAIL"
fi
```

However, this uses quite a few pipes and since I am running this command pretty often to monitor my servers, I am wondering if there is a "smarter" approach. I am also afraid my pipes might not work properly when the ping command failes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another **`awk`** variation:

```
ping -qc1 google.com 2>&1 | awk -F'/' 'END{ print (/^rtt/? "OK "$5" ms":"FAIL") }'
```

- `-F'/'` - treat slash `/` as field separator

Example output:

```
OK 47.090 ms
```

Comment: Nice, relying on the last line being kept for `END` processing!

Comment: Thanks, seems to be the nicest solution. Although it was not faster than my way, it seems more elegant.

Answer (score 5):

There’s not much you can do with `ping` itself, but you can do all the processing in AWK, reducing the number of pipes, processes etc.:

```
ping -qc1 google.com 2>&1 | awk -F/ '/^rtt/ { printf "OK %.2f ms\n", $5; ok = 1 } END { if (!ok) print "FAIL" }'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not too concerned about the exact error message then how about

```
ping  google.com | grep -Po "time.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the *status* (and not *milliseconds* etc), you can just `if` it. This work for my usecase:

```bsh
if ping -q -c 1 192.168.8.8 2>&1 > /dev/null ; then
    echo "Ok"
else
    echo "Fail"
fi
```